# How to avoid UITableViewCell repeat add custom label when TableView scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a custom Cell :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RecruitmentResumeEntity.h"

@interface RecruimentListItemCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) RecruitmentResumeEntity *entity;
@end
```

and In setting entity method in .m file I add three label:

```
-(void)setEntity:(RecruitmentResumeEntity *)entity {

   _entity = entity;

   float labelHeight = 17;

   CGRect frame = CGRectMake(64, 45, 0, labelHeight);
   UILabel *cityLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:frame text:_entity.city backgroundColor:@"#e5986f"];
   [self.contentView addSubview:cityLabel];

   UILabel *workExperienceLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(cityLabel.x+cityLabel.width +10, cityLabel.y, 0, labelHeight) text:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@年",_entity.workExperience] backgroundColor:@"#81A0D7"];
   [self.contentView addSubview:workExperienceLabel];

   UILabel *expectSalaryLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(workExperienceLabel.x+workExperienceLabel.width +10, workExperienceLabel.y, 0, labelHeight) text:_entity.expectSalary backgroundColor:@"#94C373"];
   [self.contentView addSubview:expectSalaryLabel];
}
```

In Controller cellForRowAtIndexPath method get custom cell and set entity. But when I run app,scrolling the UITableView, I found that the cell repeat create three label and I just want each cell only has three Label. Did I get something wrong or missing . Can anyone can help me ? Waiting for you help.Thanks.
[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   RecruitmentResumeEntity *entity = _dataList[indexPath.row];
   RecruimentListItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RecruimentListItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.entity = entity;

   return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a problem where you are not properly RE-using the cell.

When you call `RecruimentListItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RecruimentListItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];` the system hands you a cell that it thinks can be re-used to display information for the next cell that it needs to display, but it is solely your responsibility that this cell is properly prepared before you reuse it.

For this purpose you will have to implement `-(void)prepareForReuse` in `RecruimentListItemCell`, in there you will have to make sure that all items that need to be repopulated in the cell are reset properly so that when the cell can be repopulated properly.

For example, if in `RecruimentListItemCell` you are adding a label "SampleLable" as a subview, but you do not do `[SampleLable removeFromSuperView]` in `-(void)prepareForReuse` then every time the cell is reused, "SampleLable" will be added to it again and again, eventually you will notice that things dont look as they should, as is the case with your "repeat create label"

This is how `prepareForReuse` looks in one of my apps:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {

[super prepareForReuse];

[_statesView.activityIcon1 setHidden:YES];
[_statesView.activityIcon2 setHidden:YES];

_title.text = nil;
_infoText.text = nil;
_createdTime.text = nil;
_cellType = CustomCellTypeNone;

[_progressView setProgress:0];
}
```

Here you can see that some items I just set to nil (not always the best approach), if needed these are just put in again. You can see that I hide activityIcon 1 and 2. 
When the next cell comes up, if it needs the icons it simply unhides them, if it needs the labels then it adds them.

So if I dont nil all the labels, what happens is that they stay in the view and the next cell might add its own labels, this will lead to the problem that you are encountering.

Answer (score 1):

You can make these three labels as properties of `RecruimentListItemCell` and initialise them with lazy loading.

```
- (UILabel *)cityLabel
{
    if (!_cityLabel) {
        _cityLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:frame text:nil backgroundColor:@"#e5986f"];
        [self.contentView addSubview:cityLabel];
    }
    return _cityLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)workExperienceLabel
{
    if (!_workExperienceLabel) {
        _workExperienceLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(cityLabel.x+cityLabel.width +10, cityLabel.y, 0, labelHeight) text:nil backgroundColor:@"#81A0D7"];
        [self.contentView addSubview:workExperienceLabel];
    }
    return _workExperienceLabel;
}

- (UILabel *)expectSalaryLabel
{
    if (!_expectSalaryLabel) {
        _expectSalaryLabel = [self createTagLabelWithFrame:CGRectMake(workExperienceLabel.x+workExperienceLabel.width +10, workExperienceLabel.y, 0, labelHeight) text:_entity.expectSalary backgroundColor:@"#94C373"];
        [self.contentView addSubview:expectSalaryLabel];
    }
    return _expectSalaryLabel;
}
```

And  you only need to setText for these label within selector `setEntity:`.

```
-(void)setEntity:(RecruitmentResumeEntity *)entity {

    _entity = entity;

    float labelHeight = 17;

    [self.cityLabel setText:_entity.city];

    [self.workExperienceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@年",_entity.workExperience]];
    self.expectSalaryLabel setText:_entity.expectSalary];
}
```

In order to make a fine reuse, you can override selector `prepareForReuse`.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    _cityLabel.text = nil;
    _workExperienceLabel.text = nil;
    _expectSalaryLabel.text = nil;
}
```

Besides, you can override selector `layoutSubviews` for layout.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That because tableView reuse cell so It repeating create you UILabel, you can remove the three UILabel before you create it!

Answer (score -1):

You can use by comparing `cell == nil` condition before generating any cell.

```
static NSString *recruitmentTableIdentifier = @"RecruimentListItemCell";

RecruimentListItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:recruitmentTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[RecruimentListItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:recruitmentTableIdentifier];
}
```

Hope, it'll work. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please check whether issue regarding auto-layout constraints.