# iOS Semi-transparent View On a Tableview Cell Bleeding onto Other Cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

On my tableview controller, some cells have a semi-transparent view over them that denotes a deactivated cell for the user.  When my tableview first appears, the cells are properly displayed with the semi-transparent view on the proper cells.  However, when I scroll through the tableview such that a cell without the semi-transparent view on it goes out of sight and then refresh, the semi-transparent view bleeds over onto that cell.  All other elements of the cell are okay except that this semi-transparent view is now on it.

Displaying the semi-transparent view on a cell relies on a BOOL named "active" that is given to me when I pull down the data from the backend before the cells are ever populated.  Since I am not computing this BOOl or anything else on the spot, I am not sure why the view is bleeding.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: Will you please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to clear **background color** of cells add this method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
 [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Cells are reused. If you are adding it from the table view controller the view will still be there the next time the cell is used. You may end up with many layers of this view getting added to the cell.

The semi-transparent view should be a permanent part of the cell that you show or hide when needed, not something added when the cell is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

However you added the semi transparent view, remove it in the method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//Remove transparent view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are not using `prepareForReuse` in your cell.
Without looking at any code, I would guess that you using `prepareForReuse` improperly or perhaps not at all.

A cell needs to be cleaned up and brought back to an initial state before it can be reused, if you do not do that then what you add to a cell could show in any random cell when the former is reused.

You should take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781239/how-to-avoid-uitableviewcell-repeat-add-custom-label-when-tableview-scrolling/34783696#34783696) to get more details.

Let me know if you need any more help.